# How to prove there exists a set $B$ such $\mathrm{card}(B)>\dfrac{n}{3}$?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, extremal-combinatorics

**Question:**

> Let $a_{i}\in\mathbb N^{+}$, and the set $A=\{a_{1},a_{2},\dots,a_{n}\}$. Show that there exists a set $B\subset A$, such that $\mathrm{card}(B)>\dfrac{n}{3}$, and that for any $x,y\in B$, then $x+y\notin B$.

This problem is from China Nankai university math competition today. How prove this? Thank you.

Maybe this problem is an old problem, but I can't find it.

**At last, I find a similar problem: let the set $A=\{1,2,3,\dots,2n,2n+1\}$, and the sets $B$ such $B\subset A$, and for any $x,y\in B$, then $x+y\notin B$. Find $\max |B|$.**

The answer is $\max |B|=n+1$. For a full solution (mathematical induction) see BBs:http://zhidao.baidu.com/question/260607678.html

But for this I can't prove it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried induction on $n$?

Comment: Yes,I have try it,But at last I can't,Thank you

Comment: I have a not-working argument. Dividing $A$ to three mod 3 classes, $A_0, A_1, A_2$. If $card(A_1)$ or $card(A_2)$ is greater than $\dfrac{n}{3}$, then we are done.

Comment: @frabala: Have _you_ tried induction on $n$?

Answer (score 0):

A paper by Erdős ("Extremal problems in number theory", Matematika 11:2 (1967); [pdf](https://static.renyi.hu/%7Ep_erdos/1965-02.pdf)) has a very nice short argument for this. It's a more sophisticated version of the remark by Ma Ming in comments on the question.

Take any $\alpha$ and consider $B_\alpha=\{\,a_i\,:\,\frac13\leq (\alpha a_i \bmod 1)<\frac23\,\}$. Note that $B_\alpha$ always has the required sum-free property.

The average of $|B_\alpha|$ for $\alpha$ in some large interval -- say of width $T$ -- equals, by "interchanging the order of integration", the sum over the $a_i$ of the fraction of that large interval in which $\frac13\leq (\alpha a_i \bmod 1)<\frac23$, which is $\frac13+O(1/T)$. So the *average* of $|B_\alpha|$ can be made at least as close as we like to $\frac13$, and so the *maximum* can too.

Thus far, I'm just paraphrasing Erdős. But this argument, as it stands, doesn't *quite* solve the problem: it gets $\geq\frac n3$, not $>\frac n3$. If $n$ isn't a multiple of 3, this is enough, but what if it is?

Well, in this case we can take advantage of the fact that our $a_i$ are all integers. If we take $T$ to be, say, 1 then the average of $B_\alpha$ is *exactly* $\frac13$. So either the max is strictly bigger than this and we're done, or else $|B_\alpha|$ is always exactly equal to $n/3$. But the latter isn't true, because if $\alpha$ is very small then $B_\alpha$ is empty. And now we're done.