# How find the smallest $m$ such this $|A|=n,|B|=m,A\subseteq B$

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

**Question:**

> Let $n \geq 5$ be a positive integer and let $A$ and $B$ be sets of integers satisfying the following conditions:

> i) $|A| = n$, $|B| = m$, and $A$ is a subset of $B$.

> ii) For any distinct $x,y \in B$, $x+y \in B$ iff $x,y \in A$.

> Determine the minimum value of $m$.

Oh, sometimes I guess this answer is
$$m_{\min}=3n-3.$$
This guess relies on this post: [How to prove there exists a set $B$ such $\mathrm{card}(B)>\dfrac{n}{3}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680893)
In order to explain this question detail I take an example such that $$A=\{2,4,6,\dots,2n\},B=\{2,4,6,\dots,2n,2n+2,\dots,4n-2\}.$$
This example doesn't solve my problem
because $2+(2n+2)=2n+4\in B,2\in A,$ but $2n+2\notin A$.

Comment: If $A \subseteq B$, then $n = |A| \le |B| = m$, so $m = \dfrac{n-1}{2}$ can't be correct.

Comment: I think $ m_{\min} \le {n \choose 2} $

Comment: @hjpotter92,How can you have this?

Comment: $B$ should have the sum of all pairs of integers from $A$.

Comment: @hjpotter92: you also need all the elements of $A$ because $A \subset B$

Comment: I think $m_{\mathrm{min}}\ge 2n$

Answer (score 1):

An upper bound for $m$ is $3n-3$.  Let $A=\{k+1,k+2,k+3\dots k+n\}$, $B$ is what is required-$\{k+1,k+2,k+3\dots k+n,2k+3,2k+4,2k+5\dots 2k+2n-1\}$  We need to make $k$ large enough that $4k+7 \gt 2k+2n-1$ or $k \gt n-4$